# How to pass Unicode string as argument to urllib.urlencode()

Tags: python

I'm using Microsoft's free translation service to translate some Hindi characters to English. They don't provide an API for Python, but I borrowed code from: tinyurl.com/dxh6thr

I'm trying to use the 'Detect' method as described here: tinyurl.com/bxkt3we

The 'hindi.txt' file is saved in unicode charset.

```
>>> hindi_string = open('hindi.txt').read()
>>> data = { 'text' : hindi_string }
>>> token = msmt.get_access_token(MY_USERID, MY_TOKEN)
>>> request = urllib2.Request('http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Detect?'+urllib.urlencode(data))
>>> request.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer '+token)
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
>>> print response.read()
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">en</string>
>>>
```

The response shows that the Translator detected 'en', instead of 'hi' (for Hindi). When I check the encoding, it shows as 'string':

```
>>> type(hindi_string)
<type 'str'>
```

For reference, here is content of 'hindi.txt':

```
हाय, कैसे आप आज कर रहे हैं। मैं अच्छी तरह से, आपको धन्यवाद कर रहा हूँ।
```

I'm not sure if using string.encode or string.decode applies here. If it does, what do I need to encode/decode from/to? What is the best method to pass a Unicode string as a urllib.urlencode argument? How can I ensure that the actual Hindi characters are passed as the argument?

Thank you.

** Additional Information **

I tried using codecs.open() as suggested, but I get the following error:

```
>>> hindi_new = codecs.open('hindi.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 671, in read
    return self.reader.read(size)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 477, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Here is the repr(hindi_string) output:

```
>>> repr(hindi_string)
"'\\xff\\xfe9\\t>\\t/\\t,\\x00 \\x00\\x15\\tH\\t8\\tG\\t \\x00\\x06\\t*\\t \\x00
\\x06\\t\\x1c\\t \\x00\\x15\\t0\\t \\x000\\t9\\tG\\t \\x009\\tH\\t\\x02\\td\\t \
\x00.\\tH\\t\\x02\\t \\x00\\x05\\t'"
```

Comment: In which encoding did you save the file? Did you try to use `codecs.open` instead of plain `open` to get the file content with the correct encoding?

Comment: You show `hindi_string` defined but not `hindi`. Please show `repr(hindi)`.

Comment: Read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Also I highly recommend the `requests` library for doing any HTTP stuff.

Comment: @Bakuriu I tried codecs.open() as suggested, but I got the error (updated above)

Comment: @eryksun That was a type. Error fixed and repr(hindi_string) output updated above.

Comment: You're using `data = {'text': hindi}`, not  `data = {'text': hindi_string}`. If the text is already UTF-8, there's nothing to do. Don't decode it. Otherwise you have to decode to Unicode and encode to UTF-8.

Comment: @eryksun My apologies... typo once again. Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is `utf-16`, so you need to decode the content before sending it:

```
hindi_string = open('hindi.txt').read().decode('utf-16')
data = { 'text' : hindi_string.encode('utf-8') }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening the file using `codecs.open` and decode it with `utf-8`:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('hindi.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    hindi_text = f.read()
```